# How to apply bevel with modifier only on edges created by boolean

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, bevel

I'm trying to bevel only the edges that was generated by boolean operation none destructively on modifiers, just like the edges on the screenshot, without affecting other edges. Angle option won't cover since there are other sharp edges besides the new edges created by the boolean operation. Any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bevel modifier's `limit method` has an option called `vertex group`. Select that as the limit method. Manually select what you want beveled and assign it to a new vertex group. Reference this vertex group in the bevel modifier to only bevel what you've selected.